# How can ruby calculate the sum of huge numbers

Tags: ruby

So I wrote a basic program in ruby which calculates the n-th fibonacci number:

```
 def fib(n)
   return 0 if n == 0
   nums = [0, 1]
   for i in 2..n do
     nums.push(nums[i-1] + nums[i-2])
   end
   return nums[n]
end
```

And now I can easily call it with basicly whatever number n I like, f.x. 200,000.

So I was just wandering how does ruby manage to do that? How is it capable of calulating such a huge numbers and give the right result?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at. Ruby is a computer language. Computers are good at computing, that's why they are called computers. Why would it *not* give the right result?

Comment: Because in most languages an overflow would occur or the number would be represented as a floating point number with poor precision.

Comment: This is explained in the Bignum documentation, tutorials and many pages around the internet. Where did you search?

Comment: I did not search for anything including Bignum, simply because I did not know of its existence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby is using [Bignum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Bignum.html) under the hood for large numbers to avoid overflows. Here's is a good article that explains the process. http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/1/9/how-big-is-a-bignum